# initializer element is not constant error

Tags: cocoa-touch

i am declaring cg-point or rect as const it giving above error any one help this,,

```
#import "newViewController.h"
#import "first.h"

const CGPoint point=CGPointMake(50,50);
```

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You can't use a function (`CGPointMake`) as global variable initialization in C.

But you could do it like this:

```
const CGPoint point = {50.0f, 50.0f};
```

Comment: @jeeva: CGPointMake is a run-time function, but C expects a compile-time constant in that initialization call.